# lazy loading angular path 404

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to implement lazy loading with child routes in Angular, but I'm encountering an issue. Here's the relevant code:

In `app-routing.module`:

```
{
  path: 'reporting',
  loadChildren: () => import('./reservations/reporting/reporting.module').then(m => m.ReportingModule)
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In reporting module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: ReportRoomComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'list', component: ReportListComponent },
      { path: 'update/:id', component: UpdateReportsComponent },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ReportingRoutingModule { }
```

I've imported the necessary modules and components correctly.

The issue I'm facing is that when I try to access the paths, I always get a 404 error. Here's a screenshot of my project structure and the error:
[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZSHG.png)

[get error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyaSV.png)

[app routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlVzg.png)

[child module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJEa1.png)

[child routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHISP.png)

I've tested the routing without parent-child paths, and it works without any problems. However, when I try to implement lazy loading, Angular doesn't work as expected.

I've also verified that the lazy-loaded module is correctly imported in app-routing.module.ts and that the path to the lazy-loaded module is correct.

If anyone could help me identify the issue or provide guidance on what might be causing the 404 errors, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

ReportRoom html code : ( added )

```
<router-outlet>
<div class="content-page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="site-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <form [formGroup]="reportForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                            <!-- Chambre Selection -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="numeroChambre" class="form-label">Numéro Chambre:</label>
                                <select formControlName="chambre" id="numeroChambreSelect" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choisissez une chambre</option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let room of allRooms" [value]="room.idChambre">{{ room }}</option>
                                </select>
                                <div *ngIf="reportForm.controls['chambre'].touched ">
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['chambre'].errors?.['required']">
                                        The room number is required.
                                    </small>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Problem Type Selection -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="problemType" class="form-label">Type de problème:</label>
                                <select formControlName="problem" id="problemTypeSelect" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choisissez le type de problème</option>
                                    <option value="BINOME">BINOME</option>
                                    <option value="CHAUFFAGE">CHAUFFAGE</option>
                                    <option value="EAU">EAU</option>
                                    <option value="GAZ">GAZ</option>
                                    <option value="AUTRE">AUTRE</option>
                                </select>
                                <div *ngIf="reportForm.controls['problem'].touched ">
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['problem'].errors?.['required']">
                                        you have to choose the problem type please
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Description Input -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description" class="form-label">Description:</label>
                                <input formControlName="description" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" name="description">
                                <div *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].touched ">
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].errors?.['required']">
                                        Description is required.
                                    </small>
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].errors?.['minlength']">
                                        Description must be at least 10 characters long.
                                    </small>
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].errors?.['maxlength']">
                                        Description cannot be more than 20 characters long.
                                    </small>
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].errors?.['pattern']">
                                        Description can only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Date of Report Input -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="dateReport" class="form-label">Date of Report:</label>
                                <input formControlName="dateReport" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Report" name="dateReport">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Submit Button -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5" value="Submit Report">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</router-outlet>
```

Report list html :

```html
<div class="content-page">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="my-4">
        <h2 class="mb-4">Liste des Report</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table table-strip">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Probleme</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Date report</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let report of reports">
                <td>{{ report.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ report.problem }}</td>
                <td>{{ report.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ report.dateReport }}</td>
                <td>
                   <button class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="navigate(report.id)">✔ Modifier</button> 
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="deleteReport(report.id)">✘ Supprimer</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: please share the contents of ReportRoomComponent html file!

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that the content is present inside router-outlet tag which might be causing some issues can you please change it to

```
<div class="content-page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="site-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <form [formGroup]="reportForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                            <!-- Chambre Selection -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="numeroChambre" class="form-label">Numéro Chambre:</label>
                                <select formControlName="chambre" id="numeroChambreSelect" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choisissez une chambre</option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let room of allRooms" [value]="room.idChambre">{{ room }}</option>
                                </select>
                                <div *ngIf="reportForm.controls['chambre'].touched ">
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['chambre'].errors?.['required']">
                                        The room number is required.
                                    </small>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Problem Type Selection -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="problemType" class="form-label">Type de problème:</label>
                                <select formControlName="problem" id="problemTypeSelect" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choisissez le type de problème</option>
                                    <option value="BINOME">BINOME</option>
                                    <option value="CHAUFFAGE">CHAUFFAGE</option>
                                    <option value="EAU">EAU</option>
                                    <option value="GAZ">GAZ</option>
                                    <option value="AUTRE">AUTRE</option>
                                </select>
                                <div *ngIf="reportForm.controls['problem'].touched ">
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['problem'].errors?.['required']">
                                        you have to choose the problem type please
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Description Input -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description" class="form-label">Description:</label>
                                <input formControlName="description" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" name="description">
                                <div *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].touched ">
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].errors?.['required']">
                                        Description is required.
                                    </small>
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].errors?.['minlength']">
                                        Description must be at least 10 characters long.
                                    </small>
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].errors?.['maxlength']">
                                        Description cannot be more than 20 characters long.
                                    </small>
                                    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="reportForm.controls['description'].errors?.['pattern']">
                                        Description can only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Date of Report Input -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="dateReport" class="form-label">Date of Report:</label>
                                <input formControlName="dateReport" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Report" name="dateReport">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Submit Button -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5" value="Submit Report">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- changed here -->
```

Comment: thank you Naren i got it but on the button of the page i should scroll down to get it , 
also i try http://localhost:4200/reporting/list i got nothing i will update code html for list 
thank you very much

Comment: i have problem with localhost:4200/reporting/list 
when i go to this path i got 404 wile i import it using children route

Comment: even when i try to add with form reporting i get 404 error , when iwas working without lazy loading it was working without problem and also when i try with swagger on back it's working also

Comment: @eyajoma
could you provide a basic stackblitz with the issue replicated, also did you change any basehref for the angular project?

Comment: sorry i don't know stackblitz is it possible to share code with github ?

Comment: @eyajoma ok sure

Comment: hello sir i got it the problem was i have to add  <base href="/">  
on index.html